# Split text by "whitespace" (as seen in Firefox inspect) in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, firefox

There are several questions out there about how to split text by whitespace, but I couldn't find one that answers my question.  I'm using Python & Selenium to collect some text from a website. The text I want to collect looks like this when I view it using Firefox's "Inspect Element"

[image: Firefox html image with "whitespace"]

I don't see the same thing when I look the HTML in Google Chrome (the image below is for a different item/car than the original Firefox image):

[image: Google Chrome html shows no "whitespace"]

I want to capture each of the lines separately (e.g. ['2012', 'HONDA', 'ACCORD 4C', 'LX']).  If I use something like `elem.text.split(' ')` then I'll end up with ['2012', 'HONDA', 'ACCORD',  '4C', 'LX'] which is NOT what I want/need.

When I `print(elem.text)` I get this regardless of browser:

> 2012 HONDA ACCORD 4C LX

`elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')` gives the following regardless of the browser:

```
2012 HONDA ACCORD 4C LX
```

`elem.get_attribute('outerHTML')` gives the following regardless of the browser:

```
<div class="class_name">2012 HONDA ACCORD 4C LX</div>
```

### Edit/Update

I went to the website in Firefox then performed a "Save Page As..." with the Format equal to "Web Page, complete".  The HTML in that region of the page looks like this:

```
<div class="class1" id="id1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <div class="class4">2020 CHEVROLET SUBURBAN 4X2 V8 PREMIER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there some way for Selenium to recognize what Firefox is seeing here and split the text based on the "whitespace" indicator?

Comment: Can you `print(elem.text)` and add output to your question?

Comment: I added the output of `print(elem.text)` to the question.

Comment: Can you please share the url you're looking at?  or- share the source code as text (not an image) with right click > view page source?  - i'm wondering  if the page source has a whitespace character that python doesn't recognise as you expect and the inspection tools are being over clever (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace)

Comment: Please post your HTML in text format?

Comment: When you get the source you'll be probably see the whitespace is actually a br tag or something . If you use selenium to get the outer html or inner html you'll get a parable string.  Just post a link or the actual text and we can help :-)

Comment: Added the innerHTML and outerHTML output to the question

Comment: How about a url so we can try  and post a solution instead of guessing and getting feedback with a days lag on comments? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately the webpage is behind a login screen :(

Comment: @Jed then we'll have to deal with the lag of comments! :-)  ... OK, so i see you added a chrome devtools image. Can you run my innner/outerhtml  with chromedriver isntead of firefox?  - it looks like you might be able to split on the `"` character if reading it from chrome.   Is chrome even an option?

Comment: @RichEdwards, I got the same results in the 'innerHTML' and 'outerHTML' in chrome that I got in firefox.  My code is setup to switch between chrome and firefox with just the flip of a variable.  I prefer firefox because I have some issues with memory in chrome.

Comment: @Jed with the little bit of code you shared i can't recreate the issue. If i can't get access the page then you'll need to share the html source. delivery of whitespace is controlled by the css - and when i render the code your provided i don't get the same output in devtools... you're going to need to dump a lot of code in order to allow me to recreate it :-)

Comment: @Jed you given up on this mate?

Comment: I added a sanitized version of the full HTML dump to my question.  I'm not sure how to caputre the relevant css information if it's needed.

Comment: You've got a very special site! that html doesn't render with `whitespace`. I don't want to send you down a rabbit hole but in devtools if switch to the network tab and load the page you'll see the resources as they donwload. I still reckon it's possible to automate - but i there is some rendering scripts going on... i know you say the site behind a login, but, it's at the point where i'll create an account to try and resolve it. It's going to be too difficult to detail how to investigate little bits and pieces over comments.

Comment: @Jed Can i have the homepage and some steps on what you're doing please? - i'll create an account if i can

Comment: It's a page that requires paid login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code. Change the URL as per your need. I have assumed the class as 'happy' in my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("xyz")

time.sleep(5)
mytxt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('happy')

Split_text = mytxt.text.split()

print("Year :-", Split_text[0])
print("Make :-", Split_text[1])
print("Model :-", Split_text[2])
print("Type :-", Split_text[3])
```

Output -

[image]

Note - If it solves your query then please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hi buddy, the requested output is "accord 4c" then "lx". Then you split by " " it returns the wrong sized array.   Took me a bit of time to notice that! :-)

Comment: I have made a list after the split so that we can play around with the index numbers. For 'Accord 4C" we can use `print("Model :-", Split_text[2] + ' ' + Split_text[3])`

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the "Model" has a space in it and sometimes it doesn't.  The same thing with the trim/series at the end.  So, it's impossible beforehand to know how to split the spaces, except if we can figure out how to split on the `whitespace` I'm seeing in the Firefox inspection.

Comment: Try split using .splitlines() method. Give it a try, i have not checked from my end.

Comment: .splitlines() just puts all of the text into one line like `['2012 HONDA ACCORD 4C LX']`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `whitespace` is a result of the `<pre>` tag and new lines outside of tags inside it (probably more than that too - i'm not a web developer so just had a poke around). If you can share a link to your page we can look or if you update your question with source for your page you'll hopefully see the inner workings yourself.

If you render this HTML:

```html
<pre>
    <div>
        hello again
    </div>
    <div>
        world
    </div>
</pre>
```

You'll get this in devtools:

[image: FF devtools whitepsace]

With that in mind, you have a couple of options.

You can try Chrome. This doesn't seem to render that awkward whitespace and might be more useful for scripting against your site:

[image: chome whitespace]

If you must use FF or chrome doesn't cut it, try running this code snippet - obvioulsy modify the bits you need to get your page and element:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#create this or set your URL
url = "C:\Git\PythonSelenium\StackWhitepsace.html"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

#set this to how you identify your element
elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("pre")


print("text::")
print(elem.text)
print("") #line break

print("inner::")
print(elem.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print("") #line break

print("outer::")
print(elem.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

It's a bit verbose, but this is how this the output for my simple page:

```
text::
    
        hello again
    
    
        world
    

inner::
    <div>
        hello again
    </div>
    <div>
        world
    </div>


outer::
<pre>    <div>
        hello again
    </div>
    <div>
        world
    </div>
</pre>
```

When you see the html options that selenium sees you'll be able to use  @Pythonologist 's split in the other answer to split the outcome into the parts you need.

Comment: I don't see any `<pre>` tags anywhere in the HTML.  It doesn't look like this is what's causing it.

Comment: I did say I'm not a Web developer :-).... How about using chrome? What do you see in chrome devtools?